# FOSOAuthServerBundle "Client not found"

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I am trying to use FOSOAuthServerBundle, everything is OK. I can authentificate an user with oauth/v2/auth BUT, if the username and password are good, I have this error message:

```
Client not found.
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
```

> Stack Trace
>   in /var/www/www.billtrackapp.com/vendor/friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle/FOS/OAuthServerBundle/Controller/AuthorizeController.php at line 138
>                   ->findClientByPublicId($clientId);
>               if (null === $client) {
>                   throw new NotFoundHttpException('Client not found.');
>               }
>               $this->client = $client;

Hope you can help me on this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I saw on Github that you found your issue. Could you please share the solution? I am having the same problem as you.

Comment: Same issue. Could you please share the solution?

Comment: Could you pls share your client.orm ?

Comment: @Sebastien Thiebaud How did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i dont know if this is your case but mine was in the namespace. You need to see if your client is in the Entity-s folder or Model-folder and depends on the implementation you are doing. Hope this helps. My Client code:

```
    <?php

    // src/Azimut/ApiBundle/Entity/Client.php

    namespace Azimut\ApiBundle\Entity;

    use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client as BaseClient;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Client extends BaseClient
    {
     /**
       * @ORM\Id
       * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
       * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
       */
        protected $id;

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();

        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```